# NumPy mean of multiple slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

Let's say I have an array `a` where I would like to calculate the mean across multiple slices defined in `idx`:

```
a = np.arange(10)
idx = np.random.choice([0,1], a.size).astype(bool)

a, idx
Out[1]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
         array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True,
                True]))
```

With the desired output:

```
array([2.5, 8. ])
```

Of course I could write a simple `for` loop, but I would prefer a fully vectorized approach given that the arrays sizes can become quite big and 2D.

Comment: Can you clarify how your desired output is formed? Maybe with that explicit for loop?

Comment: @orlp Sure, something along these lines: ```[np.mean(a[i[0]:i[1]]) for i in [[2,4],[7,10]]]```. You'd first have to convert the boolean array to indices, but after you've done that you could run this for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do it completely vectorized:

```
edges = np.diff(idx.astype(np.int8), prepend=0, append=0)
rising = np.where(edges == 1)[0]
falling = np.where(edges == -1)[0]
cum = np.insert(np.cumsum(a), 0, 0)
means = (cum[falling] - cum[rising]) / (falling - rising)
```

This takes about 0.2 seconds on my machine with `a = np.arange(10**7)`.

Comment: Terrific, thanks for helping! I'll try on a 2D array as well.

Comment: For 2D arrays change @orlp 's bottom two lines of code to:
```cum = np.insert(np.cumsum(a, axis=1), 0, 0, axis=1)```
```means = (cum[:, falling] - cum[:, rising]) / (falling - rising)```